# How can I avoid "An error occurred submitting the edit" error message? (working July 13th)

Tags: bug, edits, answers, error-message

July 13th: it works again, so far.

July 12th: I have (again) some of my answers I cannot edit (others can edit them, but I cannot)

- "[How to make git maintain a git.properties file containing select information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39205630/6309)"
- "[Can we mount subdirectories of a named volume in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38167198/6309)", July 2016
- "[How do I reference an existing branch from an issue in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15757712/6309)", Dec. 2022
- "[Add livedoc-mocha to existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76560648/6309)", June 27th, 2023, two weeks ago!

---

July 10th, 11th: it works

---

From July 1st, up to July 10th: I have some answers I am unable to edit:

- "[Unable to star/unstar a GitHub repo when using the GitHub API (GitHub App integration)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76576261/6309)", which I had to delete and recreate.(so you need 10K to see the deleted one)
- "[push --force-with-lease by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726130/6309)", which I cannot delete and recreate.
- "[Clerk and Svix web hooks not working with error: "src property must be a valid json object"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76578326/6309)"
- "[In git, is there a way to show untracked stashed files without applying the stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66831429/6309)"
- "[Multiple defers vs deferred anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55878049/6309)"
- "[Is there any way to make a draft pull request using git bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70714679/6309)"
- "[Trying to sign commits on git using gpg on WSL, but does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57620087/6309)"
- "[Updating pull request after review changes commit doesn't show up in the pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627449/6309)" (I managed to edit it once, and then... no more edit possible)
- "[Rules for special characters in GitHub repository name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59082561/6309)"
- "[Understanding git rev-list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64398354/6309)"
- "[How Do I Use `GIT_CONFIG` Environment Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68697328/6309)"
- "[How to retrieve the right commit hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56202726/6309)"
- "[Replicate IntelliJ merge commit details functionality in CLI + vanilla git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76496753/6309)"
- "[Reconnect ClearCase view to its Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76632035/6309)" (from 2 days ago!?)

Basically, any answer older than a few days can no longer be edited.

In all cases, on multiple computer/browsers (Firefox/Chrome latest version, even through new session in incognito mode):

[image: An error occurred submitting the edit]

Even if I delete the content and enter a simple sentence, it fails.
Which means the issue might be in the original content I want to replace.

- the first answer did not include any obvious special characters
- the second answer included "Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason"
- the third has no special characters

In all instances, no matter how many times I submit an edit, or how long I wait between them, the result is the same: "An error occurred submitting the edit".

This is confirmed even from a Firefox in safe mode, with 0 plugins.

---

I see, when editing the [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726130/6309):

```json
{
    "POST": {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "stackoverflow.com",
        "filename": "/posts/43726130/edit-submit/d8870f64-105e-48ce-8708-a5e2eeccf9c3",
        "remote": {
            "Address": "10.196.48.246:8080"
        }
    }
}
```

Request:

```
is-current=true&post-text=%3E+I'm+worried+that+I+might+forget+about+this+nifty+feature+the+next+time+I+need+it.++%0D%0A%0D%0AGit+2.13+(Q2+2017)+explains+why+there+is+no+%22protection%22+against+this+push+option+being+forgotten%2C+because+even+if+you+*do+not*+forget+it+at+the+%60git+push%60+level%2C+it+might+still+be+ignored.++%0D%0A++%0D%0ASee+%5Bcommit+f17d642%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgit%2Fgit%2Fcommit%2Ff17d642d3b0fa64879d59b311e596949f2a1f6d2)+(19+Apr+2017)+by+%5B%C3%86var+Arnfj%C3%B6r%C3%B0+Bjarmason+(%60avar%60)%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Favar).++%0D%0A%3Csup%3E(Merged+by+%5BJunio+C+Hamano+--+%60gitster%60+--%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgitster)+in+%5Bcommit+46bdfa3%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgit%2Fgit%2Fcommit%2F46bdfa3975665aaa9b7383466b529354d117e14d)%2C+26+Apr+2017)%3C%2Fsup%3E++%0D%0A%0D%0A%3E+%23%23+%60push%60%3A+document+%26+test+%60--force-with-lease%60+with+multiple+remotes%0D%0A%3E%0D%0A%3E+Document+%26+test+for+cases+where+there+are+two+remotes+pointing+to+the+same+URL%2C+and+a+background+fetch+%26+subsequent+%60git+push+--force-with-lease%60+shouldn't+clobber+un-updated+references+we+haven't+fetched.%0D%0A%3E%0D%0A%3E+**Some+editors+like+Microsoft's+VSC+have+a+feature+to+auto-fetch+in+the+background%2C+this+bypasses+the+protections+offered+by+%60--force-with-lease%60+%26+%60--force-with-lease%3D%3Crefname%3E%60**%2C+as+noted+in+the+documentation+being+added+here.%0D%0A%0D%0ASo+the+%5Bdocumentation+for+%60git+push%60%5D%5B1%5D+now+includes%3A%0D%0A%0D%0A%3E+general+note+on+safety%3A+supplying+this+option+without+an+expected%0D%0Avalue%2C+i.e.+as+%60--force-with-lease%60+or+%60--force-with-lease%3D%3Crefname%3E%60%0D%0Ainteracts+very+badly+with+anything+that+implicitly+runs+%60git+fetch%60+on%0D%0Athe+remote+to+be+pushed+to+in+the+background%2C+e.g.+%60git+fetch+origin%60%0D%0Aon+your+repository+in+a+cronjob.%0D%0A%3E%0D%0A%3E+The+protection+it+offers+over+%60--force%60+is+ensuring+that+subsequent+changes+your+work+wasn't+based+on+aren't+clobbered%2C+but+this+is+trivially+defeated+if+some+background+process+is+updating+refs+in+the+background.+We+don't+have+anything+except+the+remote+tracking+info+to+go+by+as+a+heuristic+for+refs+you're+expected+to+have+seen+%26+are+willing+to+clobber.%0D%0A%3E%0D%0A%3E+If+your+editor+or+some+other+system+is+running+%60git+fetch%60+in+the%0D%0Abackground+for+you+a+way+to+mitigate+this+is+to+simply+set+up+another%0D%0Aremote%3A%0D%0A%3E+%60%60%60%0D%0A%3E+git+remote+add+origin-push+%24(git+config+remote.origin.url)%0D%0A%3E+git+fetch+origin-push%0D%0A%3E+%60%60%60%0D%0A%3E+Now+when+the+background+process+runs+%60git+fetch+origin%60+the+references%0D%0Aon+%60origin-push%60+won't+be+updated%2C+and+thus+commands+like%3A%0D%0A%3E+%60%60%60%0D%0A%3E+git+push+--force-with-lease+origin-push%0D%0A%3E+%60%60%60%0D%0A%3E+Will+fail+unless+you+manually+run+%60git+fetch+origin-push%60.++%0D%0AThis+method+is+of+course+entirely+defeated+by+something+that+runs+%60git+fetch+--all%60%2C+in+that+case+you'd+need+to+either+disable+it+or+do+something+more+tedious+like%3A%0D%0A%3E+%60%60%60%0D%0A%3E+git+fetch++++++++++++++%23+update+'master'+from+remote%0D%0A%3E+git+tag+base+master++++%23+mark+our+base+point%0D%0A%3E+git+rebase+-i+master+++%23+rewrite+some+commits%0D%0A%3E+git+push+--force-with-lease%3Dmaster%3Abase+master%3Amaster%0D%0A%3E+%60%60%60%0D%0A%3E+I.e.+create+a+%60base%60+tag+for+versions+of+the+upstream+code+that+you've+seen+and+are+willing+to+overwrite%2C+then+rewrite+history%2C+and+finally+force+push+changes+to+%60master%60+if+the+remote+version+is+still+at+%60base%60%2C+regardless+of+what+your+local+%60remotes%2Forigin%2Fmaster%60+has+been+updated+to+in+the+background.%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A++%5B1%5D%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgit%2Fgit%2Fblob%2Ff17d642d3b0fa64879d59b311e596949f2a1f6d2%2FDocumentation%2Fgit-push.txt%23L221-L249&fkey=e9c8e83b24f18cf42c00e373ef80268c3ec0a208056f57d29f77d8ec432723e7&author=&edit-comment=format+answer
```

But the response is a 500, with the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" HTML page!?
(`[HTTP/2 500 Internal Server Error 30154ms]`)

The draft `POST` does work, though:

```json
{
    "POST": {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "stackoverflow.com",
        "filename": "/posts/43726130/editor-heartbeat/edit",
        "remote": {
            "Address": "10.196.48.246:8080"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind if I try editing, to see if it's only you (as the author) running into an issue? For what it's worth, I've seen this sort of thing *transiently* before, but it was simply because of my own unstable Internet connection.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sure, go ahead (don't edit the first one, since I had to delete/recreate it, and the new one can be edited)

Comment: Okay, I hit submit on my edit for the second one, to join up the multi-paragraph block quotes and put code blocks inside the block quotes properly. It went flawlessly, so I'm not sure what to tell you at this point. Perhaps check if you can re-edit now?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for this test. I confirm I *still* cannot edit that particular answer. Same error.

Comment: But you can edit other answers?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, all the time. Except for those three.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I manage to do a simple edit to the second answer (the one you edited). And then... any subsequent edit on that same answer went right back to the same error message.

Comment: @VonC do you think it's worth it to try with another browser?

Comment: @pierpy I have tried them all (Firefox, Chrome, Edge), on different computer, on W10 and W11, with different networks. The error is a server one (HTTP error 500). I need Stack Overflow support to have a look at server logs... but it is the fourth of July after all ;)

Comment: Ok, 500... I did'nt see!

Comment: "Basically, any answer older than a few days can no longer be edited." Ah, well there seems to be a specific pattern to it; so in that case I'll remove the `specific-answer` tag again.

Comment: I've just started getting errors trying to edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592600/1491895) of my own. I ended up posting a new answer, which was successful, and I was able to edit that one.

Comment: [More confirmation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425486/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-edit-hidden-oops-something-bad-happened).

Comment: And [another one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425495/editing-a-cw-answer-results-in-http-500-server-error) (I think).

Comment: I just got this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76690808/16343464), impossible to edit…

Comment: @mozway My ticket 108262 was closed as "Your device was hitting one of our system restrictions used to combat spam and/or fraud. Unfortunately, at this time, I am not able to lift this restriction.". Not exactly trust-inspiring...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

July 13th: it does work, again...

---

July 12th: it does not work, again...

---

Update one week later (July 10th, Monday): <del>edits seem to work now</del>.

I will confirm later today (on different computers) if that is still the case.

Confirmed: it finally works!

I would be interested in any feedback from the team as to what went wrong for more than a week, though.