# Editing a CW answer results in HTTP 500 server error

Tags: bug, edits

### Bug report

I have found a CW post I made where I can reliably replicate a server crash. I have triggered it several times over a week or so, in the hope it had already been fixed. The latest instances were "Sat, 08 Jul 2023 09:43:00 GMT" and "Sat, 08 Jul 2023 09:59:37 GMT" based on the server response headers.

The AJAX operation returns a whole-page HTML error rather than JSON (which may be a secondary bug):

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

### Replication notes

For general readers, please don't try replicating the bug - it may work for you, and then be harder/impossible to replicate subsequently. Please leave it for a Stack Overflow engineer. I assume this is an edge case, since editing works fine for most people (and mostly it works fine for me too).

The answer [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75857122/golang-dependency-injection-for-mock-database-in-unit-testing/75876995#75876995). I click on the "edit" link and change the text "OP" to "question author". I put in an edit reason of "Clarify wording". I then click on "Save edits".

Following a long delay, an error is shown in the web app. The delay is 30 seconds, which makes me wonder if there is a database timeout.

The payload is thus:

```
is-current=true&post-text=_(Posted+answer+on+behalf+of+the+question+author+to+move+it+to+the+answers+section)_.%0D%0A%0D%0AIt+seems+like+the+only+way+to+solve+this+issue+is+to+create+multiple+TestMain+in+packages+that+rely+on+this+test+environment+(in+my+case%2C+the+mock+database)+as+stated+in+https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fg%2Fgolang-nuts%2Fc%2FSxEkZhWl3QA.+Maybe+in+future+this+concern+will+be+added+into+Golang+where+TestMain+can+be+integrated+to+different+packages.%0D%0A&fkey=---&author=&edit-comment=Clarify+wording
```

(The `fkey` has been removed as it may carry some security/session info).

The POST operation goes to something like this (GUID obscured):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75876995/edit-submit/bbbbbbbb-ffff-4444-8888-ffffffffffff
```

Could this be looked into? I should think it would be low priority, since I am not aware of another example at the moment.

Comment: Possibly related: *[How can I avoid "An error occurred submitting the edit" error message?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425430/how-can-i-avoid-an-error-occurred-submitting-the-edit-error-message)*

Comment: Possibly related: ["An error occurred submitting the edit." (Hidden: Oops! Something Bad Happened!)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425486/2821954)

Comment: Ooh, thanks both - I should have searched more thoroughly here 

Comment: I've VtC as a dup for now 

Comment: Edits were working Monday and Tuesday, no longer working today.